# Why do main(String[] args) not accept this?

Tags: java, arrays

The code that you see here is somewhat unfinished; but I'm trying to test the push and pop function. However I keep getting an error message stating:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field stack.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

class IntegerStackGeneric extends IntegerStack {
    ArrayList<Integer> stack;

    IntegerStackGeneric() {
        stack = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void push(int x) {
        stack.add(x);
        return;
    }

    public int pop() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if(!stack.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("IntegerStackGeneric: pop()");
        }
        return stack.remove(stack.size()-1);
    }

    public int size() {
        return stack.size();
        // return -1;
    }

    public boolean contains(int x) {
        return false;
    }

    public void reverse() {
        return;
    }

    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return new ArrayList<Integer>().iterator();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        stack.push(1);
        stack.push(2);
        stack.push(3);
        System.out.println(stack);
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
        System.out.println(stack);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked for other questions about static references to non-static fields?

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> stack;` is a non-static field, but `main()` is run in a static environment. You need to create a `IntegerStackGeneric` object first, in order to access the instance field.

Comment: Runnable classes are called without getting an instance, directly from main method. So it means it has "null" instance. Static methods can be called from other classes (if they are public or callable) without getting an instance. If you define a variable out of the static method like here, then you should have same modifier with static to call it. Also you gotta initialize.

Comment: I do have an IntegerStackGeneric, look at the top

Comment: @Jacklyn: You don't have one in `main`, which is where you're trying to use it. And in fact, you don't have an *instance* of `IntegerStackGeneric` at all (there's no `new IntegerStackGeneric` in your quoted code).

Comment: `stack` is instance variable and `main` method is static method. For instance variables we have create object to access variables but for static members we don't need create an object, we can directly access them by using class name like `classname.staticfiled`

Comment: Your variable stack should be static.

Comment: @AfsinBuyuksarac: I don't think so. Instead, I think they should be using an instance.

Comment: As a true coding yes, it has to be instance variable. What I've read and mistaken of the code is "static" definition. Design of the code is another issue as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is right there in the error message:

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field stack.

Your `stack` field is an *instance* field. `main` is a `static` method, there is no instance at that point. If you want to use `stack`, you'll need an instance, e.g.:

```
IntegerStackGeneric isg = new IntegerStackGeneric();
isg.stack.push(/*...*/);
```

You'd probably want to put your logic in an *instance* method you call from `main`, rather than directly in `main` though:

```
IntegerStackGeneric isg = new IntegerStackGeneric();
isg.doStuff();
```

And:

```
private void doStuff() {

    stack.push(1);
    stack.push(2);
    stack.push(3);
    System.out.println(stack);
    System.out.println(stack.pop());
    System.out.println(stack);
}
```

Comment: I really should have known this was a duplicate, changed the answer to a non-rep-producing CW.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand; I already have an IntegerStackGeneric(), I've moved the stuff in main to a "doStuff" like you suggested. But it gives me the same error, but now in the  doStuff()

Comment: @Jacklyn: The `IntegerStackGeneric()` in your code is a *constructor*, not an expression creating an instance. (To be the latter, it would have to be inside something [a method, for instance], and have `new` in front of it.) I suggest working through some Java tutorials, [such as this one on classes and objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

Comment: T.J., Jacklyn is trying to implement a stack by himself/herself. I think; at least I got him/her wrong. Actually s/he needs to get an instance of her IntegerStackGeneric class in main method. Then s/he can use her methods. @Jacklyn I edit your code could you please try that.

Comment: @ AfsinBuyuksarac so should I make IntegerStackGeneric a method and call for it in main?

Comment: @Jacklyn: No, you should do what I said above: *Create an instance*.

Comment: @AfsinBuyuksarac *"I edit your code could you please try that."* Since your edit got rejected, you should learn how Stackoverflow works, first. [This help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) explains _when_ you should edit a question. Your edit wasn't appropriate.

Comment: Jacklyn, get an instance of your class in main method.  IntegerStackGeneric stack =  IntegerStackGeneric();

Comment: The problem here, people who supports king are more than a king. @Tom this is my 4th day of this site. Maybe I don't get howto use it. My reason is trying to help, I'm not telling people what they should do. I don't have to learn how it works first to help someone. Is that a problem ? I don't really care reputation.